# How to redisplay a ViewController that IsLoaded

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I understand how to show a ViewController via Push.

However, how do I redisplay a view that has already been pushed and is still loaded, but not visible on the screen.

I tried

BaseView.PresentViewController(CurrentViewController,true,null);

But, I got this error:
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Application tried to present modally an active controller

If the viewcontroller is new, I can use a Push and it works
BaseView.NavigationController.PushViewController(CurrentViewController,true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the following method?

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewControllerLoadedAlready animated:YES]
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  I'm including the MonoTouch code here as well:  BaseView.NavigationController.PopToViewController(CurrentViewController,true);